# Python Heroku app deployment "App not compatible with buildpack" error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app in heroku, but is failing with "App not compatible with buildpack" error.
I have added requirement.txt and procfile in my project, yet it is failing.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-
buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to xyz.
```

Heroku build log is not providing much info either:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-
 buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-
 failure
!     Push failed
```

Can someone tell me if I am missing anything? I am trying git push method.

Answer (score 0):

You need more precision. Required file for python buildpack is `requirements.txt`. Make sure that you added it to your repository. Also procfile should be named `Procfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `INDEX` file to your main directory, in my case i just added `index.php` file